# Why isn't feedburner working on my WordPress Blog?

Tags: wordpress, blogs, feedburner

I seem to be having an issue setting up Feedburner on my blog. watch the video below, I believe I'm doing everything correctly.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IsyrwjdCNV0

Comment: Is it the email field on the right of http://rawadmerhi.com/gopress/ ? Because that doesn't seem to flag any error up when I test it

Comment: @enigma yeah It is, that's very odd. What happens when you test It?

Comment: redirects to [here](http://rawadmerhi.com/gopress/wp-content/plugins/newsletter/subscription/page.php?nm=confirmation&nk=8-36315123ba)

Comment: @enigma Hold on let me disable that plugin, then you can test it again.

Comment: maybe include the link to your feedburner in you main post

Comment: @enigma Did you try it?. I have removed the other plugin. Okay I will try to link it to my main post.

Comment: goes [here](http://rawadmerhi.com/gopress/wp-content/plugins/newsletter/do/subscribe.php) now - you sure you disabled it?

Comment: @enigma Yes I have, this is very odd, Whenever I hit the Subscribe button on my end, a pop up comes out saying "The feed does not have subscriptions by email enabled." On your side It takes you to another page.

Comment: @enigma I got It working :)

Comment: @enigma Would you mind checking my most recent problem?